# Spring JPA NoRepositoryBean Queries

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

How I can use `@Query` in `@NoRepositoryBean` methods with `@MappedSuperclass`?

I have **@MappedSuperclass** Temporal (Basis have Long id)

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Temporal extends Basis<Long> {

    private Long temporalCode;
    private Date dateBegin;
    private Date dateEnd;
    // getters/setters
}
```

and **@NoRepositoryBean** TemporalRepository

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface TemporalRepository<T extends Temporal> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
//    this two are ok
    List<T> findByTemporalCode(Long temporalCode);
    List<T> findByTemporalCodeAndDateBeginBeforeAndDateEndAfter(Long temporalCode, Date dateBegin, Date dateEnd);

//    query not working because Temporal is not an @Entity
//    @Query("select t from Temporal t 
//         where (t.dateBegin < ?1 or t.dateBegin is null) 
//         and (t.dateEnd < ?1 or t.dateEnd is null) ")
//    List<T> findByDate(Date date);
}
```

**Update:**
For example I have temporal entity Worker:

```
@Entity
public class Worker extends Temporal {
//    fields and methods here
}

public interface WorkerRepo extends TemporalRepository<Worker> {
//    Looks like it will work but I don't want to write the same method in each TemporalRepository subclass
//    @Query("select w from Worker w where (w.dateBegin < ?1 or w.dateBegin is null) and (w.dateEnd < ?1 or w.dateEnd is null) ")
//    List<Worker> findByDate(Date date);
}
```

Comment: not working means? are you getting some exception or something..

Comment: I guess this won't work you have write only methods in `@NoRepositoryBean` interface without @query and later on define an another repository interface without `@NoRepositoryBean` and use extends with `TemporalRepository` interface and override the methods.

Comment: Not working means getting an exception on application start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actualy you could use SpEL expressions for it.
[Spring Data JPA reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query.spel-expressions)
So we can replace name of superclass with `#{#entityName}`

Example from reference:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractMappedType {
  …
  String attribute
}

@Entity
public class ConcreteType extends AbstractMappedType { … }

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MappedTypeRepository<T extends AbstractMappedType>
  extends Repository<T, Long> {

  @Query("select t from #{#entityName} t where t.attribute = ?1")
  List<T> findAllByAttribute(String attribute);
}

public interface ConcreteRepository
  extends MappedTypeRepository<ConcreteType> { … }
```

Solution for my example:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface TemporalRepository<T extends Temporal> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
    List<T> findByTemporalCode(Long temporalCode);

    List<T> findByTemporalCodeAndDateBeginBeforeAndDateEndAfter(Long temporalCode, Date dateBegin, Date dateEnd);

    @Query("select t from #{#entityName} t 
        where (t.dateBegin < ?1 or t.dateBegin is null)
        and (t.dateEnd < ?1 or t.dateEnd is null)")
    List<T> findByDate(Date dateBegin);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

KI don't think you can do this because `@NoRepositoryBean` is used to tell spring that don't create a repository proxy bean for this interface. Such interface is used to expose some additional methods other than concrete repository interface. In that case you have to `extend` such interface, I will take another example to explain this:

Consider I have `Student` and `Teacher` entity  :

Now I have interface as:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ReadOnlyRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
  T findById(int id);
}
```

Now we have to write an concrete repo interface like:

```
public interface StudentRepository extends ReadOnlyRepository<Student, Long> {
  //override the methods of `ReadOnlyRepository` with @query
}

public interface TeacherRepository extends ReadOnlyRepository<Teacher, Long> { 

//override the methods of `ReadOnlyRepository` with @query
}
```

In this way it's possible to manually define the queries both Student and Teacher by simply declaring JPA named queries `Student.findById` and `Teacher.findById`. Using this approach you can easily come up with tailor-made base interfaces for your application scenario.

So @NoRepositoryBean is used to avoid creating repository beans.

Comment: Yep and first two methods works fine with all repos, which extend TemporalRepository in my example. But in findByDate() I have more complex logic so I need something like @Query to write select with brackets. Of course I can write findByDate() in all subclasses of TemporalRepository which will represent concrete Entities, but this methods will do the same thing. Thats why I need this method in TemporalRepository.